# Why no significant performance differences for this code with different param passing strategies?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, pass-by-reference

I am trying to write some piece of code and convince myself that *pass by value*, *pass by reference*(`rvalue` and `lvalue` reference) should have significant impact on performance ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879687/are-there-real-world-cases-demonstrating-reasonable-performance-improvement-by-u)). And later I came up with this code below and I *thought* the performance differences should be visible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

#define DurationTy std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
typedef std::vector<int> VectTy;
size_t const MAX = 10000u;
size_t const NUM = MAX / 10;

int randomize(int mod) { return std::rand() % mod; }

VectTy factory(size_t size, bool pos) {
  VectTy vect;
  if (pos) {
    for (size_t i = 0u; i < size; i++) {
      // vect.push_back(randomize(size));
      vect.push_back(i);
    }
  } else {
    for (size_t i = 0u; i < size * 2; i++) {
      vect.push_back(i);
      // vect.push_back(randomize(size));
    }
  }
  return vect;
}

long d1(VectTy vect) {
  long sum = 0;
  for (auto& v : vect) sum += v;
  return sum;
}

long d2(VectTy& vect) {
  long sum = 0;
  for (auto& v : vect) sum += v;
  return sum;
}

long d3(VectTy&& vect) {
  long sum = 0;
  for (auto& v : vect) sum += v;
  return sum;
}

int main(void) {
  {
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    long total = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM; ++i) {
      total += d1(factory(MAX, i % 2)); // T1
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << total << std::endl;
    auto elapsed = DurationTy(end - start);
    std::cerr << elapsed.count() << std::endl;
  }
  {
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    long total = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM; ++i) {
      VectTy vect = factory(MAX, i % 2); // T2
      total += d1(vect);
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << total << std::endl;
    auto elapsed = DurationTy(end - start);
    std::cerr << elapsed.count() << std::endl;
  }
  {
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    long total = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM; ++i) {
      VectTy vect = factory(MAX, i % 2); // T3
      total += d2(vect);
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << total << std::endl;
    auto elapsed = DurationTy(end - start);
    std::cerr << elapsed.count() << std::endl;
  }
  {
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    long total = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM; ++i) {
      total += d3(factory(MAX, i % 2));  // T4
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << total << std::endl;
    auto elapsed = DurationTy(end - start);
    std::cerr << elapsed.count() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I tested it on both `gcc`(4.9.2) and `clang`(trunk) with `-std=c++11` option.
However I found that *only* when compiling with *clang* `T2` takes more time (for one run, in milliseconds, 755,924,752,750). And I also compiled the `-fno-elide-constructors` version but with similar results.

(**update**: there are slight performance differences for `T1`, `T3`, `T4` when compiled with Clang (trunk) on Mac OS X.)

My questions:

- What are the optimizations applied that bridge the potential performance gaps between `T1`, `T2`, `T3` in theory? (You can see that I also tried to avoid RVO in `factory`.)
- What is the possible optimization applied for `T2` by gcc in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An rvalue of type `vector<T>` will have its guts stolen by another `vector<T>` if you try to construct the second `vector<T>` from it.  If you assign, it may have its guts stolen, or its contents may be moved, or something else (it is underspecified in the standard).

Constructing from an identical rvalue type is called move construction.  For a vector, (in most implementations) it consists of reading 3 pointers, writing 3 pointers, and clearing 3 pointers.  This is a cheap operation, regardless of how much data the vector holds.

Nothing in `factory` stops NRVO (a kind of elision).  Regardless, when you return a local variable (in C++11 that exactly matches the return value types, or in C++14 that finds a compatible rvalue constructor) it is implicitly treated as an rvalue if elision does not occur.  So the argument in `factory` will either be elided with the return value, or have its guts moved.  The different in cost is trivial, and any difference could then be optimized away anyhow.

Your three functions `d1` `d2` and `d3` should be better called "by-value", "by-lvalue" and "by-rvalue".

The call L1 has the return value elide into the argument to `d1`.  If this elision fails (say you block it) it becomes a move construct, which is trivially more expensive.

The call L2 forces a copy.

The call L3 has no copy, and neither does L4.

Now, under the as-if rule, you can even skip copies if you can prove it can have no side effect (or, more accurately, if eliminating it is a valid variant under the standard for what could happen).  gcc may be doing that, which would be a possible explanation for why L2 is no slower.

The problem with benchmarks of pointless tasks is that, under as-if, once the compiler can prove the task was pointless, it can eliminate it.

But I'm not surprised that L1 L3 and L4 are identical, as the standard mandates that they be basically identical in cost, up to a few pointer shuffles.

Comment: For `factory` you mean it's the rule in C++11/C++14 that avoids the copy(either due to stolen or move construction); and that is different from pre-C++11 standard; for case `T2`, you mean the first construction (at Line `T2`) still avoids copy but the call to `T1` forces the copy. Right?

Comment: `T2` I am using to refer to the body of the loop.  The call to `d1` forces a copy on the line after the `T2` comment.  Everything mentioned is assuming a baseline of C++11, with some C++14 comments thrown in.  In C++03, what you did in `factory` is unlikly to block NRVO either (barring no-elide flag), but there is no rvalue constructor nor implicit treat-as-rvalue rule.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of r-value references. you are passing in std::vector by value- which compiler figures out has move constructor and optimizes the copy to move.

See following link for details about rvalue refs: http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html

update:
The following three methods turn out equivalent:

In here, you are passing in return of factory directly in function `d1`, compiler knows that the value returned is a temporary and `std::vector (VectTy)` has a move constructor defined- it just calls that move constructor (so this function is equivalent to `d3`

```
long d1(VectTy vect) {
  long sum = 0;
  for (auto& v : vect) sum += v;
  return sum;
}
```

Here you are passing by reference so no copy- OTOH and this shouldn't have compiled. unless you are using MSVC- in that case you should disable language extensions

```
long d2(VectTy& vect) {
  long sum = 0;
  for (auto& v : vect) sum += v;
  return sum;
}
```

Of course there won't be any copy here, you are moving temporary vector (rvalue) from factory to d3

```
long d3(VectTy&& vect) {
  long sum = 0;
  for (auto& v : vect) sum += v;
  return sum;
}
```

If you want to reproduce the copying performance issues, try rolling out your own vector class:

```
template<class T>
class MyVector
{
private:
    std::vector<T> _vec;

public:
    MyVector() : _vec()
    {}

    MyVector(const MyVector& other) : _vec(other._vec)
    {}

    MyVector& operator=(const MyVector& other)
    {
        if(this != &other)
            this->_vec = other._vec;
        return *this;
    }

    void push_back(T t)
    {
        this->_vec.push_back(t);
    }
};
```

and use this instead of `std::vector`, you will for sure hit the performance problem you are looking for

Comment: Could you explain in detail?

Comment: For `T3` I deliberately created `vect` and then pass it to `d2`.

Comment: For `d1`, do you mean that during parameter passing like `VectTy vect = temporary_vector`, the `constructor` is move constructor?

Comment: For the wrapper you provided, I added `begin`/`end` iterator and removed `operator=` but still could not reproduce the performance differences. Maybe the compiler is wise enough to find that there is no side effect and optimize to `std::vector`?

Comment: change your NUM to MAX and try again

Comment: I changed MAX and created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/HongxuChen/4b7dc302bbb38daf601d) for the running result. It seems that `MyVector` is not optimized, however there are still no big performance differences between `T1`, `T3`, `T4`.